# VSCode - Php unit test?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm making a test.php and trying to unit test this.

It's my first time ever unit testing in VSCode in PHP.

My code looks like:

```php
<?php
    
    class TestCase extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
    {
        public function test(){
            $this->assertTrue(false);
        }
    
        public function test1(){
            $this->assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

But when I hover the TestCase and press (F1) and choose (Better PHPUnit: Run), its saying "No task to run found. Configure Tasks..."

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

If I'm supposed to add a Task... Which one should I choose and how do I navigate it to my test.php?

Answer (score 0):

If still wondering, check on your vscode user settings the key `"task.autoDetect": "off"` and make sure to delete it or set it to `"task.autoDetect": "on"`